# Interacting a time varying covariate with a function of time

Tags: survival

i have estimated an exponential model (proportional hazard-rate metric) while the baseline is modelled using restricted cubic splines. This was done by splitting the observed duration time at any observed time point and set up the restricted cubic spline terms.

Additionally, i model one covariate effect as time dependent (non-proportional) by interacting the covariate with the restricted cubic spline terms and investigating the effect via a plot of the predicted time dependent hazard ratio.

However, the covariate is time varying (change the value over time) which is also realized by splitting the observed duration time if a change of the covariate is observed.

The datastructure looks good and all works fine but i frequently ask myself: Is it a sensibel strategy to interacting a time varying covariate with a function of time?

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 1):

Yes. From your description it looks like you use something like a piece-wise-exponential model, where the piece-wise constant baseline hazard in each interval is estimated by a spline.

In the context of a PEM the time $t$ is simply considered a covariate, thus a sensible model specification for the log-hazard in interval $j$ with time-varying effects would be

$$\log(\lambda(t;x)) = \beta_0 + f_0(t) + f_x(t)*x$$
where $f_0(t)$ is the non-linear part of the baseline-hazard and $f_x(t)*x$ is the time-varying effect of $x$. Both, $f_0(t)$ and $f_x(t)$ can be estimated by (penalized) splines or specified as known functions. 
In practice, the time-dependent functions $f_0$ and $f_x$ are evaluated at some fixed time-points within each interval.

Consider the example [here](https://adibender.github.io/pammtools/articles/tveffects.html) for illustration.